# Can I estimate the audience size given the city and the language?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I need to mimic the behavior of the targeting selection screen, just make it simpler, limiting the choice to few languages and a few hundred cities, see the picture of the original screen below. I tried calling

```
curl -G  \
  -d 'targeting_spec="{"geo_locations":{"countries":["BE"],"zips":[{"key":"BE:1000"}],"locales":[{"key":"1003"}]}}' \
  -d 'access_token=TOKEN' \
```

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/act_AD_ACCOUNT_ID/reachestimate

but I get the message

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "The entity backed by id ENTITY_ID cannot be seen by the viewer with (ViewerID 0, AccountID 0): DENY_RULE:InlinePrivacyPolicy:AlwaysDenyRule:4 (EntID: ENTITY_ID)",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 1
  }
}
```

Should I ask for more permissions from Facebook? And how? I am just trying to build a simple website app.

[image: Facebook Audience targeting]

Comment: Are you sure the user whose access token you're using to make the API calls has access to the ad account in question, and that you've granted the correct permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have ads management scope added to your access token and as I take it you are in development mode you need to ensure that the ad account that you are sending requests for is on your account list
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access#standard_accounts

Your curl command should be as follows:
- You don't need countries and zips as part of geolocations as they overlap
- locales is not part of geo_locations and is not an array of key/value pairs - it is an array of ints.

```
curl -G  \
-d 'targeting_spec={"geo_locations":{"zips":[{"key":"BE:1000"}]},"locales":[1003]}' \
-d 'access_token=[access_token]' \
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/[account_id]/reachestimate
```

Comment: Bingo, it works. The biggest problem for me was to figure out what this [account_id] actually is.